# How to keep picture box right side of table lay out in window form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, tablelayoutpanel

How to get picture box image at right side in `TableLayoutPanel` in c#? At present I am getting image next line of label but i need picture box text beside a label in `TableLayoutPanel`.Here is my code

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
pb.ImageLocation = ../imagesDT/answered.gif
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
```

I am trying to keep image beside the label in `TableLayoutPanel`, but at present getting image below the label.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Form4 : Form {

    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox() { BackColor = Color.RosyBrown, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    Label lb = new Label { Text = "Label", AutoSize = true };
    TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    public Form4() {
        Controls.Add(panel);
        panel.Controls.Add(lb, 0, 0);
        panel.Controls.Add(pb, 1, 0);
    }
}
```